# Anchoring Tabs with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

How do I use `react-router` to create a link with an anchor for one of my pages?

Example: I want something like: **mysite.com/#/nodes/10#instances**

This would direct someone to the route handled by `/nodes/:id` and then select the tab (`react-boostrap` tabs) on that page that corresponds with "instances".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use a `<Link />` [component](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/IndexRoutes.md), but you can't use a double hash for the specific link you want. Event with history routing (which doesn't use a hash for the URL) this is [not supported](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/HashHistoryCaveats.md#caveats-of-using-hash-history) in react-router (see the last paragraph).

Comment: Is it supported using `createBrowserHistory` instead of `createHashHistory` ?

Comment: No, there is now way to get this working with the hash. You could hack together something using the querystring.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a listener for hash changes. This is a native javascript event `window.onhashchange` (for more see this  [hash change event MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange))

You could have a top level component containing all the tabs as sub components and just render the specific tab based on the hash value of the url. If the hash changes, you can update state/props to re-render and display the new tab.